# Mapping an nhibernate many-to-one to an inteface

Tags: nhibernate

I would like to map an Nhibernate many-to-one property to an interface like the following if that is possible:

public

```
public interface IContact
{
    Guid Uid { get; set; }
    string FirstName {get;set;}
    //etc. etc.
}
```

I am fairly sure I can only map to concrete types but maybe somebody can point out a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all described in the docs: [Chapter 8. Inheritance Mapping](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance)

Depending on the chosen strategy, you'll map the reference property as `many-to-one` (most cases) or `any` (only if you use implicit polymorphism)

Answer (score 0):

You can map to an interface ... and it works exactly as it does for concrete classes.